# Rendering of old page after MVC application is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Everytime I publish the MVC application, the old version of page is shown instead of new one. How can I resolve this problem?

I have to tell the users to clear their browser history, every time the application is published.

Is it a good approach to add the below code snippet in Global.asax?

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   .....
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   .....
 }
```

Comment: Where is the page hosted - for example azure or your own server? The problem could be in the IIS server cache configuration settings.   Do you have client side code (like Angular or similiar). Do you cache something on the clients (indexdb, session, storage)?

Comment: @keenthinker, the application is deployed on **IIS** server. Clientside is basically razor with javascript. Session is used for managing session.